# Temporary tables and constant statement recompilation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, stress-testing

I am stress testing a system that is using a temporary table in dynamic SQL. The table is created early on in the transaction and is filled by several dynamic SQL statements in several stored procedures that are executed as part of the batch using statements of the form:

```
INSERT #MyTable (...)
SELECT ...
```

where the `SELECT` statement is reasonably complicated in that it may contain `UNION ALL` and `UNPIVOT` statements and refer to several UDFs. All strings are executed using `sp_executesql` and Parameter Sniffing is enabled.

I have noticed that under load I am seeing a lot of RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE waits where the query text being recompiled is present and *identical* in several waits at the same time and appears throughout the stress test which lasts about 5mins. The memory consumption on the server usually sits around 60% utilization and there is no limit on how much SQL Server can consume. The limiting factor appears to be CPU, which is constantly at >95% during the test.

I have profiled the server during the test to observe the SQL:StmtRecompile event which highlights the reason for the recompile is:

> 5 - Temp table changed

but the temp table is the same every time and there are no DDL statements performed against the table once it has been created, apart from when it is dropped at the end of the batch.

So far, I have tried:

- Enabling the "optimize for ad hoc workloads" option
- `OPTION(KEEPFIXED PLAN)`
- Changing the dynamic statement to just the `SELECT` and then using `INSERT ... EXEC` so the temp table is not in the executed string

All of these have made no difference and the waits persist.

Why would SQL think that is needs to recompile these identical queries each time they are executed and how can I get it to keep and reuse the cached plans it is creating?

Note: I cannot change the temp table to an In-Memory table because sometimes the stored procedures using this may have to query another database on the same instance.

This is using SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU7.

Comment: This blog shows similar issue you are facing,it says `Some other common reasons for recompiles relating to temporary tables include: declare cursor statements whose select statement references a temporary table, or in an exec or sp_executesql statement. `

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/18/11-0-temporary-tables-table-variables-and-recompiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that removing the insertion into the temp table in the dynamic SQL strings improves performance significantly. For example, changing this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql
    N'INSERT #tempTable (...) SELECT ... FROM ...'
```

where the `SELECT` statement is non-trivial, to this:

```
INSERT #tempTable (...)
EXEC sp_executesql
    N'SELECT ... FROM ...'
```

greatly reduced the number of blocks created during compilation. Unfortunately, recompilation of the queries is not avoided it's just that the queries being recompiled are now much simpler and therefore less CPU intensive.

I have also found it more performant to create an In-Memory Table Type with the same columns as the temp table, perform the complex insertions into a table variable of that type and perform a single insert from the table variable into the temp table at the end.

Comment: Referring to #tempTable from inside the dynamic SQL I think indeed causes excessive recompilations, as per http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables : "If a stored procedure refers to a temporary table not created statically in the procedure, the spid (process ID) gets added to the cache key. This means that the plan for the stored procedure would only be reused when executed again by the same session."

Comment: Also based on ["If a temporary table is created with an OPTION (RECOMPILE) statement then the optimizer will need to recompile every statement it touches."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/) I _guess_ a "Temp table changed" recompile on a query accessing a temp table may be caused by a preceeding "Statistics changed" recompile of the "SELECT INTO #tempTable" statement, that created the temp table...